# Byobu screen default for all users

Tags: configuration, byobu, gnu-screen

I have installed `byobu` in my ubuntu 12.04 server installation and set as backend to use screen.

What i am trying to do without success is to have all users on my system to use `byobu` having also screen as default.

I have tried to use `byobu-select-backend`, but this will change the setting only for the user issuing the command and not all.

I don't want to edit for every user on the system manually the `.byobu/backend`, but what i am trying to achieve is when i install it, i.e as a `root` user this setting to be applied for all users on the system.

Thank you all in advance.

Regards.

Kostasp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/byobu/backend` and replace the assignment

```
BYOBU_BACKEND="tmux"
```

with

```
BYOBU_BACKEND="screen"
```

Uncomment the line also if it is commented on your system.

This system-wide configuration file will affect all users. Of course, users are still free to select a tmux session if tmux is installed, and each user's `~/.byobu/backend` will take precedence over the system-wide default, but the default will now be screen for all users that have not yet run byobu.

If you want to set the default for users even if they have already run byobu and have their own preferences, then you will have to edit (or delete) each user's individual `~/.byobu/backend` configuration file.